# C++ term for an object that can be iterated through begin and end

Tags: c++, iterator, iterable

**iterator** is the generic word for something that can iterate a collection of objects.

On the other hand, I'm not sure that there is a commonly accepted word in C++ for the collection itself, in particular when the object provides `begin` and `end` methods.

**Question**: in C++, is there a commonly accepted word for an object that can be iterated through `begin` and `end` methods ?

The term **iterable** sounds quite reasonable for this (as a matter of fact, the tag exists on SO). I just wonder if it can be *officially* used as an answer to the question.

Comment: Seems like opinion based.

Comment: *"wonder if it can be officially used as an answer to the question..."* No, there is no term called "iterable" in c++ unlike python.

Comment: One of best books on C++ uses the term **sequential container**.

Comment: the named requirement *Container* has `begin` and `end`, but it has much more. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container

Comment: @user12002570, *container* is maybe too strong since the iterated items could be created on the fly and so the object doesn't really contains the items.

Comment: @edrezen Your use of the term "collection" in your question is not any different from the term "container".

Comment: "range" is a term that is often used. However a range is a more general than what you are looking for. Usually its not that useful to require `begin` and `end` as members. I suppose reading about the range based for will help https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++20 calls this a "range". As noted in the comments, the definition of a range is slightly more broad than what you suggest, to include e.g. plain arrays that don't have `.begin()` and `.end()` members. You're expected to use `std::ranges::begin(...)` and `std::ranges::end(...)` instead of the member functions to get those iterators.

C++20 added ways to check if a type conforms to those requirements at compile-time: [`std::ranges::range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range) and others.